# Laravel - getting results from products table where i'm matching the results with attributes table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have these tables

```
| products |                 | products_attributes |

id name and ..                id  product_id taste expire
```

**Product Model**

```
public function attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsAttributes::class);
    }
```

**ProductAtributes Model**

```
 public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

all other attributes are in products table and can easily add them to the filter query, but i dont know how to add products with their taste filter to the query because the taste is in attributes table.

**this is my filter function in Controller**

```
public function showCategory(Request $request, $id){
        $catt = Category::findorfail($id);
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $catt->id)->where('status', '1')
            ->orderBy('brand_id', 'ASC');

        if(!empty($_GET['brand'])){
            $brandArray = explode('-', $_GET['brand']);
            $products = $products->whereIn('brand_id', $brandArray);
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['weight'])){
            $weightArray = explode('-', $_GET['weight']);
            $products = $products->whereIn('product_weight', $weightArray);
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['count'])){
            $countArray = explode('-', $_GET['count']);
            $products = $products->whereIn('product_count', $countArray);
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['taste'])){
            $tasteArray = explode(',', $_GET['taste']);
            foreach ($tasteArray as $taste){
                $attr = ProductsAttributes::where('product_taste','LIKE', "%$taste%")->with('product')->get();

                $products = $products->merge($attr);
            }
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['sort'])){
            $sort = $_GET['sort'];
            $products = $products->reorder('selling_price', $sort);
        }

        $products = $products->paginate(12);

        return view('pages.show_category', compact('products', 'catt'));
    }
```

Comment: Does the record you're searching for has to match all the value from $tasteArray or if it matches at least one of the values should it be included in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like so.

```
$products = Product::orderBy("id","ASC");

if(!empty($_GET['taste']){
  $tasteArray = explode(',', $_GET['taste']);
  foreach($tasteArray as $item){
    $products = $products->whereHas("attributes",function($query) use($item){
       $query->where("taste","LIKE","%".$item."%");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me just need to add `use ($item)` to the `function($query)`
thanks

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot.